# Migrate Microsoft Access database to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am facing an issue when trying to migrate the Microsoft access 2007 database to SQL Server 2014 (I don't own the Access database and user just wants it to be migrated to SQL Server). Please help me resolving this issue.

I have tried..

1.SQL Import/Export wizard for migrating data from access DB to SQL Server db.
2. SSMA tool for migration.
3. Also tried followed using the below method.

https://www.thoughtco.com/convert-access-database-to-sql-server-1019925

Using SSMA ...... it says that the Access database is protected by a work group policy.. though I provided the location, user name and password it is not accepting.

Using SQL Server IMPORT/EXPORT wizard: it says you do not have the necessary permissions to use the `.mdb` object and have your system administrator or the person who created this object establish the appropriate permissions for you.

Using Microsoft Access: it says that close the objects before proceeding with the action.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Surprisingly, that problem is part of [Preparing Access databases for migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/preparing-access-databases-for-migration-accesstosql?view=sql-server-ver15) ;)

Comment: Just remove security and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have a good number of issues here.

First, you saying work group policy, or do you mean work group security?

There is a MASSIVE and Mount Everest of a difference between the two here.

Also, since you note and mention that this is an mdb file, then it is certainly possible that Access work group security exists and is in place for this database.

What I would do then is remove workgroup security first and THEN migrate to sql server. You might be able to get the various tools to work with workgroup security in place, but it only takes 2-3 minutes to move the database to a non secured accDB.

And I do recommend you use an Accdb, since that is what the last 10 or so years of the SSMA been designed to work with.

So, you do not mention what version of Access you have here, but let’s assume Access 2010.

The first thing you need to do is determine WHICH security work group file the application or data file is using.

The simplest way is to look at the application shortcut they are using to launch the application. In fact, if there is no start-up forms, then simply launch the application (hold down shift key to prevent start-up forms). Given that you using the shortcut that ALSO includes the workgroup file, then at this point, you are logged into and connected to that mdb database with ALSO the correct workgroup file. In fact, if on launch of the application you get a user and password logon, then you can be rather confident that the database is using workgroup security.

The key concept here is to ensure you are using the correct workgroup file (.mdw) that is matched up with the mdb file.

Once you logged in, and of course held down the shift key, then you should be at the full access application UI/interface. At that point you ARE connected to the workgroup file. So simply close the database but DO NOT exit access. The reason for this is you will remain connected to the workgroup file. At this point, create a new blank accdb file. Now, simply import all of the data tables from the old mdb file into this new accDB file you just created (and have still open in access). Because you are STILL connected to the workgroup file, then you should have no problem importing all of the tables from the mdb file into the AccDb file. The key concept here is you need to be joined to, and part of that correct workgroup file. But, the act of creating a new accDB file will not be secured (despite the fact that you are still connected to the workgroup file).

At this point, you can exit access. Now re-launch access (you’re not connected to the workgroup file anymore – so no logon prompts should occur. And now take a quick look to see if the table have data – they likely will.

So, now at this point in time you have a regular and un-secured accDB file. At this point, you are now free to migrate the data to SQL server. I suggest using the SSMA, as it has a ton of features that you require. The other methods you attempted are possible to use, but SSMA will keep your indexes, and more important your relations between the data intact after migrating to sql server. Having to re-create the gazillion indexes, and setup table relationships is a lot of work, and only SSMA really keeps all of that stuff intact during a migration to sql server.

It also not clear however if in addition to just some data tables, you ALSO have forms, code, reports?

I don’t think it needs to be pointed out that forms, reports, code, VBA is NOT a database, but NOW you talking about a developed application. I also refrain from pointing out how crazy it is to NOT distinguish between data, or a database migration and that of creating, or fixing an application designed to work with access that now must work with SQL server.

To be fair, if you have experience doing such migrations, then you know exactly what to look for, and exactly what is required to make an Access application designed to work with a mdb file now to work with SQL server. Depending on how large the application is what will determine how much work the application part, and what kinds of modifications are required.

So a data migration tends to be rather easy, and with tools like SSMA it’s most simple.

However now that you migrated the data part (easy), the significant amount of work starts on making the application part work with SQL server, and for that you better have some rather good access skills.

It also not clear if you have a mdb file for the forms, reports and MOST important the VBA code, since you need not only skills to dive deep into the application code, but you also need the “source” code, or the ability to look at, and modify the code behind the forms. I ask this question, since often the developer may have setup a special password that ONLY let them modify the forms and code – but every other user can only use forms etc.

Data migration from Access to SQL, or migrating data say from Oracle to SQL server tends to be rather easy. After all, you just moving tables of data.

However, the REAL challenge, the REAL meat and the real issue is after you moved the data to SQL server, then what tools and software are you planning to use to work with that data that now resides on SQL server?

So it’s not clear if this is JUST a data migration project to move some Access data tables?

Or does this project also involve the developer (software) side of things in which you THEN need some working software to work with SQL server. The tools to move data are automated, and takes no time at all. But the application part and the software parts are manual, and labour intensive, and require Access developer skills.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation as yours. The Access database we have was created by, and purchased from, a company that's no longer in business. If all you want to do is import the data (and not connect the old Access database to the SQL Server), create a new access database and connect it to the old database. Doing this, I was able to see and link to the tables in the locked down database. From there you can import them from the new database to SQL.